# Python sqlite table updates using HTML

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am adding a table in html that displays a the results of an sqlite fetchall and serves the html using flask but I need a way for specific rows of records to be deleted by a user on the front end side and in the database. Is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help in advance!

My HTML table:

```
   <table style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
               <thead>
                  <td>Column 1</td>
                  <td>Column 2</td>
                  <td>Column 3</td>
                  <td>Update</td>
                  <td>Delete</td>
               </thead>
               
               {% for row in rows %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{row["row1"]}}</td>
                    <td> {{row["row2"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{row["row3"]}}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" id="remove">Update Row</button></td>
                    <td><button type="button" id="remove">Delete Row</button></td>  
                  </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

My Python Code:

```
@app.route('/database', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def database():
    connection = sqlite3.connect(r'')
    connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    datasearch = "select * from Items where ID= " + str(session['ID'])
    print(datasearch)
    cursor.execute(datasearch)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template("database.html", rows = rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onClick` in the `button` tag to trigger sending a URL, similar to

```
<button onClick='window.location.href="/database/delete/{{row["row1"]}}"'>
```

although there are nested quote marks there.  The usual way to handle these things is to put the row inside a <form>, with <input> fields that includes the data you want to send.